# Use tar -xvf to decompress one file generated by dd，and it returns success, why it happens?

Tags: linux

```
root@fushion:/tar_test# dd if=/dev/zero of=tar.bin  bs=1M count=15

15+0 records in
15+0 records out
15728640 bytes (16 MB, 15 MiB) copied 0.109188 s, 144 MB/s
root@fushion:/tar_test# tar -xvf tar.bin 
root@fushion:/tar_test# echo $?
0
root@fushion:/tar_test#
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of a tar file is a series of 512-byte blocks. The initial blocks are file entries, and the last file is followed by two blocks consisting only of zero bytes, which indicates the end of the archive.

The file you created with `dd` has no files, it just starts with the end-of-archive blocks. Reading an empty archive is not an error. Would you expect `cat /dev/null` to report an error?

Comment: Thank you very much！ Now I know the reason. If it is an empty file, is it more reasonable to return failure when decompressing？ Maybe my idea is naive.

Comment: I don't think an empty file should be valid, since it's missing the end-of-archive blocks, but I just tried `tar xf /dev/null` and it didn't get an error, either.

Comment: Thank you all the same, I just do it for test.